# TLS 1.2 Client Hello failure

Tags: java, ssl, sslhandshakeexception

I have a Java app that I use to automate pulling down data from NOAA. It has worked fine up to this week when it suddenly failed on the TLS handshake. Looking at the debug trace it is receiving a fatal alert from the server on the initial Client Hello:

```
*** ClientHello, TLSv1.2
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1557742545 bytes = { 197, 46, 181, 254, 21, 83, 77, 65, 33, 85, 238, 194, 203, 141, 5, 105, 252, 60, 193, 124, 125, 111, 213, 237, 107, 20, 110, 136 }
Session ID:  {}
Cipher Suites: [TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
Compression Methods:  { 0 }
Extension elliptic_curves, curve names: {secp256r1, secp384r1, secp521r1}
Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]
Extension signature_algorithms, signature_algorithms: SHA512withECDSA, SHA512withRSA, SHA384withECDSA, SHA384withRSA, SHA256withECDSA, SHA256withRSA, SHA256withDSA, SHA1withECDSA, SHA1withRSA, SHA1withDSA
Extension extended_master_secret
***
[write] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 179
main, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 179
[Raw write]: length = 184
[Raw read]: length = 5
0000: 15 03 03 00 02                                     .....
[Raw read]: length = 2
0000: 02 28                                              .(
main, READ: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
main, RECV TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, handshake_failure
```

I thought perhaps the server had changed its supported algorithms so I ran nmap:

```
443/tcp open  https
| ssl-enum-ciphers:
|   TLSv1.2:
|     ciphers:
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (secp256r1) - A
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (secp256r1) - A
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (secp256r1) - A
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 (secp256r1) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (rsa 2048) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (rsa 2048) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (rsa 2048) - A
|     compressors:
|       NULL
|     cipher preference: server
|_  least strength: A
```

So there is agreement on at least two of the cipher suites. I can point a web browser at the web page I am trying to read into my Java app and that works fine. I did notice that the server had replaced its server cert in the last week, but the TLS connection in my Java app is failing before it even gets to the point where the server is sending its certificate, and in any event, it is the server that is aborting the handshake.

I noticed the GMT field in the Random Cookie is supposed to be the current time at the client but the number being sent is off by several months. Not sure if that is a problem; it is out of my control as far as I know, and yes my system clock is correct. Obviously the server doesn't like something in the Client Hello but what that is I cannot figure out, but it must be related to the new certificate that they installed. I looked at the Cert, it is signed by both SHA256 and SHA1, both of which are supported on the client.

I don't think this is Java coding problem. I think it is a configuration issue. I am using JRE 1.8.0_231-b11.

The URL of the web page is: https://ndbc.noaa.gov/data/realtime2/51205.spec

Comment: The cert chain used by that server are all signed with SHA256+RSA, as standards have required since 2015; I don't know what you see as a SHA1 signature and an X.509 cert can't have multiple signatures (unlike PGP). But as you said your error occurs before sending or receiving the certs, and is not caused by them. Oracle Java since 144 (I think 141,2 also but I missed them) by default in `java.security` rejects SHA1 signatures for TLS certs _under the predefined CAs_ (including Starfield); this complexity can't be expressed in the sigalgs extension, which therefore still states SHA1 support.

Answer (score 3):

Similar questions were already asked.

In fact, as shown with [SSL Labs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=ndbc.noaa.gov&s=13.35.125.87) your request is missing the Server Name extension which is required for this website. And indeed we can see 4 other extensions in the request, but not this one.
This stopped working because they changed the server configuration.
You didn't provide the client's code, but check it's not running with `-Djsse.enableSNIExtension=false` as explained in the [JSSE Reference Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#Customization)